# Partial Views don't have any style when the action has a parameter? ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

whenever i try to load a partial view, it doesn't have any style and doesn't apply java script within it.

Here is an example:
a partial view where the user is able to comment on a project.

**this is the model i'm using:**

```
public class Comment
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CommentDesc { get; set; }

    public string ProjectManagerId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProjectManagerId")]
    public ApplicationUser ProjectManager { get; set; }

    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProjectId")]
    public Project Project { get; set; }

}
```

**this is the action:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    [MyAuthorize(Roles = "Project Manager")]
    public ActionResult Comment()
    {
        return PartialView("Comment");

    }

    [HttpPost]
    [MyAuthorize(Roles = "Project Manager")]
    public ActionResult Comment(int id,Comment Comment)
    {

            var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            Comment Com = new Comment
            {
                 ProjectManagerId = userId,
                 ProjectId= id,
                 CommentDesc = Comment.CommentDesc
            };
            context.Comments.Add(Com);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Main", "Home");



    }
```

**this is where the action gets called:**

```
<a title="Comment" class="CommentProj" href='@Url.Action("Comment", "Project",new { id = item.Project.Id })'>
   <img src='~/Bikes/Comment.png' width="32px" height="32px" />
</a>
```

**and this is the Partial View:**

```
@model Trial.Models.Comment
@using (Html.BeginForm("Comment", "Project"))
{

<div class="modal hide fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Comment</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.CommentDesc, new { @class = "input-style form-control", @style = "background-color: transparent;", @placeholder = "Comment on the post", @rows = "6" })<br />
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="submit" class="put-in btn btn-succes" value="Post" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  }
```

and here is how it looks like when loaded:[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYl0J.png)

Comment: A partial view is just that, part of a view. You'd want to make a call to render your partial view from inside a full view element. Check this out for examples; https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/617361/Partial-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: Looking on your code the easiest solution will be to turn your `comment` partial view to a view and in your `comment action` you can return it. This way all styles will be applied and javascript will work so long as you either include necessary script tags or define then in a script bundle. I hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example:**

**Your Action :**

```
 [HttpGet]
    [MyAuthorize(Roles = "Project Manager")]
    public ActionResult Comment(int id)
    {
        var model= new Comment{
            ProjectId=id
        }
        return PartialView("Comment",model);

    }

    [HttpPost]
    [MyAuthorize(Roles = "Project Manager")]
    public ActionResult Comment(Comment comment)
    {    
            var com = new Comment
            {
                 ProjectManagerId = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
                 ProjectId= id,
                 CommentDesc =comment.CommentDesc
            };
            context.Comments.Add(com);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Main", "Home");
    }
```

**Your PartialView:**

```
@model Trial.Models.Comment
@using (Html.BeginForm("Comment", "Project"))
{

<div class="modal hide fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Comment</h4>
            </div>
         <form>
         //Please use Html.BeginForm OR Ajax.BeginForm OR jQuery Ajax for submit form
            <div class="modal-body">  
                @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.ProjectId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.ProjectManagerId)
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.CommentDesc, new { @class = "input-style form-control", @style = "background-color: transparent;", @placeholder = "Comment on the post", @rows = "6" })<br />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="submit" class="put-in btn btn-succes" value="Post" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
         </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
}
```

> In you question i can't understand how you `form` submit. so **please
>   use `Html.BeginForm` OR `Ajax.BeginForm` OR `jQuery Ajax` for submit
>   form**.